# MS Access to SQL 2014 Default Schema

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

When I export data from MS Access 2010 to SQL Server 2014 using an ODBC connection into a new table, it comes in correctly under the 'dbo.tablename' schema.  When my coworkers do the exact same export from Access, their schema is our domain with their username 'DOMAIN\username.tablename'.

Is there a way to change/fix this so all of their exports use the default 'dbo' schema?

Comment: You probably use Windows authentication, and your login is assigned the default schema `dbo`, but theirs isn't.

Comment: Yep, I see that now for their logins so I've changed it and will have them test.  Thanks!